# Autopilots which are compatible with ROS

Tags: ros, ros2, drone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can i find their list please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285758/autopilots-which-are-compatible-with-ros/) by [gadamer](https://answers.ros.org/users/34196/gadamer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-18

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a central authority. Ardupilot and PX4 are both known to work. Other autopilots may have support you'll likely have more accurate responses by looking at the autopilot project(s) of your interest.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0